# Applying Selenium WebDriver to Amazon

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to login to Amazon using Selenium WebDriver. I have written the following code, which I believe should have worked, but it doesn't. It throws no such element found exception, although the button with this CSS class is in there, and I can see it in view source, or inspect element.

```
driver.get("http://www.amazon.com");
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-yourAccount"));
boolean isdi = el.isDisplayed();
el.click();
WebElement el2 = driver.findElement(By.id("nav-flyout-ya-signin"));
boolean isdi2 = el2.isDisplayed();
WebElement el3 = el2.findElement(By.cssSelector("nav-action-button"));
boolean isdi3 = el3.isDisplayed();
el3.click();
```

Comment: First of all here I think no meaning of your check for isdisplayed() because you have not put any condition like if isdisplayed() true then get element.

Comment: It looks your css selector is incorrect.